# XeTeX problem compiling when I have a table

Tags: tables, xetex, lyx

I'm trying to compile using XeTeX and I get this error

```
 ...ab:Quizzes-open-times}Quizzes open times}

Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.
```

I know the problem is with the table I have at the end. If I remove it, I can compile the document.

How can I solve this?

LyX: https://www.dropbox.com/s/pmjfirn6qq9av5g/fancyhdr_question.lyx

tex: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jko0wujfxybzxfx/fancyhdr_question.tex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this solved the problem:

```
 \DeclareTextCommandDefault{\nobreakspace}{\leavevmode\nobreak\ }
```

Answer (score 4):

The error is due to the wrong loading order of packages: `hyperref` should be loaded last, while `mathdesign` must be loaded before `fontspec`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[urw-garamond]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1in,bmargin=1.5in,lmargin=1in,rmargin=1in}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}

\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 0},backref=false,colorlinks=false]
 {hyperref}

 %%%<other code without \usepackage>
```

If LyX is unable to do this, it's a really bad feature.